# Why is UINavigationBar.items an array?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Why is the `items` property of `UINavigationBar` an array? Can someone break down this class and its properties a bit more?

Consider the following code:

```swift
let item = UINavigationItem()
item.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
navBar.items?.append(item)
```

What is the purpose of having multiple `UINavigationItem`s? It seems like I would only ever need one `UINavigationItem`. I'm mostly thinking in the context of creating my own `UINavigationBar` vs using a `UINavigationController`.

I've already read the documentation, which was far from helpful:

> The bottom item is at index 0, the back item is at index n-2, and the top item is at index n-1, where n is the number of items in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at something you should never have looked at!

A UINavigationBar maintains a *stack* of UINavigationItems. These are pushed and popped onto and off of the bar, and the bar changes its interface in response.

But in real life, you will never do that, because you will use a UINavigationController and *it* does the pushing and popping. You push a view controller onto the UINavigationController, and the UINavigationController pushes the corresponding UINavigationItem onto the UINavigationBar.

No one *ever* uses a "bare" UINavigationBar and does the pushing and popping directly. You could if you wanted to, but you never will.

Comment: I am using it and that's why I'm asking, UINavigationController is doing too many things that are out of my control so I needed to implement a nav bar directly. It seems like pushing/popping on my iPhone simulator does nothing special, however pushing/popping in a CarPlay/Automaker context seems to show the usual navigation animations, oddly enough. Not sure why it doesn't happen on mobile. Either way I find this useful to understand how navigation controllers work under the hood.